# How to add OAuth github authentication to VueJS App

Tags: express, vue.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, vue-router

I have a VueJS app created using vue-cli 3.0 and I want to add OAuth based github authentication to it. Many of the tutorials I found online uses ExpressJs and/or passportjs to do OAuth flow.

If my app doesn't need Server-Side Rendering, Do I still need ExpressJs to do OAuth ..? If so, how can I can add Express to VueJs app created using vue-cli.

If Express is not needed, can anyone point me to documentation on how to add OAuth to Simple VueJs app.

Greatly appreciate you help.

Thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) page

> Note: GitHub's OAuth implementation supports the [standard authorization code grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1). You should implement the web
> application flow described below to obtain an authorization code and
> then exchange it for a token. (The [implicit grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) is not
> supported.)

To do what you want to do you need a OAuth implementation that supports [implicit grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2). But GitHub doesn't support this so you need a "backend" like for example Express.